# How can i set textbox value using css class name when document load

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I want embed arcgis map [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-search-multiplesource/index.html) as an example to my asp page for search to search employees cubicle, the map has a text box for search. I want the search to be automatic based on emplyee number or cubicle number.  i will like to display the map on the employee detail information page `/Details/Index/7`. Is it possible to load text box value automatically when page load?

here is the search textbox

```
<form class="esri-search__form" role="search">
<input type="text" placeholder="District or Senator" aria-label="Search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" class="esri-input esri-search__input" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="16e0a09202a-widget-1-suggest-menu" role="textbox" data-node-ref="_inputNode" title="District or Senator">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, having a textbox with a certain class name (I'd suggest an ID though), you can set its initial value to whatever you want using:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".esri-search__input");
elem.value = "Some value here";
```

```html
<input type="text" class="esri-search__input"/>
```

Comment: Anis, Thanks its not working for me. the map has a code in the link i provide did you have a chance to look at it?

Comment: @Kuku Do you have any other elements with the same class name in your code?

Comment: no iadded the code here https://codepen.io/kinfeg/pen/NWWgyOq?&editable=true&editors=100#anon-signup

Answer (score 0):

```
view.ui.add(searchWidget, {
position: "top-right"
});
```

You need wait this function finishing, one way is this:
    setTimeout(()=>document.getElementsByClassName("esri-input esri-search__input") 
    [0].value="Some value here", 10000);

Comment: i added `setTimeout(()=>document.getElementsByClassName("esri-input esri-search__input") [0].value="Some value here", 10000);`in the head but no luck

Comment: i added the code here https://codepen.io/kinfeg/pen/NWWgyOq?&editable=true&editors=100#anon-signup

Comment: yes it worked Thank you it sets the value but wen click search button it keeps searching i have to write into it, how can i auto click search button and making search?

Comment: try replace "Some value here" with "California" and hit search see what i am talking about. Thanks!

Comment: searchvalue is not textbox value. it's state of your map {component}. so you should find callbacks in .element.bind or in 'API' wiki on your map website to change state: document.getElementsByClassName("esri-input esri-search__input")[0].bind.searchTerm="california"

Comment: also document.getElementsByClassName("esri-search__submit-button esri-widget--button")[0].bind.search()